# Sorting multithreaded output

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

Let's say I have a program that takes a series of integers and outputs their squares. In pseudocode this might look like:

```css
For (i = 1; i = 10; i++){
  print "i squared is" >> i^2 >> endl;
  }
```

If I run this sequentially I would expect "i squared is 1", "i squared is 4", and so on in ascending order. However if I ran this in parallel, each thread would take an individual value of i and square it. There's no guarantee the thread with i = 1 will finish first, so I might have instead output: "i squared is 9", "i squared is 81", "i squared is 49" etc in pseudo-random order.

Clearly the parallel output is harder to interpret. I can change the code such that it prints both i and i^2, but even then, it's still harder to interpret. Is there a way to get the output to be in ascending order *and* still do the squaring in parallel? The question seems generic enough that surely someone somewhere must've answered it already, but my Googling only finds results on parallel sorting algorithms.

Comment: Such is the nature of multi-threaded code. The killer is in synchronising things - whether that means input data, output data, in-memory data, hardware peripherals, files, atomic variables. Have a read on atomics, condition variables, sempahores, mutexes, barrier-waits, and multithreaded synchronisation techniques.

Comment: *Is there a way to get the output to be in ascending order and still do the squaring in parallel?*  Yes, store the results as they are generated and send them to the console at the end of the computation.  Printing has no place inside parallel code - one of the major objectives of parallelisation is to increase execution speed, one of the major side-effects of printing is to decrease execution speed, they don't play well together.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark suggest writing that as an answer. Seeing it my reaction was like, 'doh, just define an array and get each thread to store its value at the corresponding location followed by printing the array, but for some reason I didn't think of it.

Comment: I'm not going to write an answer, I'm fairly sure this is a nearly-f-a-q but I haven't found a good duplicate yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering my own question since High Performance Mark all but wrote the answer in the comments - all credits to him)

*Is there a way to get the output to be in ascending order and still do the squaring in parallel?*

Yes. Define an array of length 10 and get each thread to output its value to the corresponding element in the array. This is not always easy to do (you may have to tweak the loop such that it can be run independently for each value of *for*), but the example in the OP doesn't have this problem. In pseudocode:

```css
int resarray[10]; //Declare integer array of length 10

#pragma omp parallel for //Or however you're initializing parallel code
For (i = 1; i = 10; i++){
  resarray[i] = i^2;
  } //end parallel section 

For (i = 1; i = 10; i++){ //sequential part
  print << i << " squared is " << resarray[i] << endl;
  }
```